# the background image resizes when a the swal alert 2 pop up shows

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

i coded a registration page and  i used swal alert 2 to show pop ups with messages according to the user use. For example, if the user click on the submit button without filling the labels a swal alert will appear and show the message of error. So, the user will be able to know what he did wrong.

But there is a problem when the swal alert shows, the background image is resized to another size than it should be. 
Normally the background image takes the full screen but when the swal alert appears the image takes middle of the screen.

So, i want to find an issue and keep swal alert 2 and do not change to swal alert because of the beautiful animations.

There is a link with the screen showing the problem.

[enter link description here](https://prnt.sc/qeax8e)

Comment: It seems to be some problem with your general layout. How are you importing and calling swal2?

Comment: Finally, i ended up by changing to swal alert. It works fine with it. I think that swal alert 2 makes a problem when it is combined with some bootstrap code

Comment: Good, I prefer swal over swal2 too. 90% less code.

Answer (score 0):

The sweet alert 2, define new class for your body! class="swal2-shown swal2-height-auto". If you defined your body with height: 100%, just pass swal prop, heightAuto: false!

example:
Swal({
title: `I will not change html's and body's height`,
heightAuto: false
})

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

In similar situation, for me, the following fixed it:

```
body.swal2-shown > [aria-hidden="true"] {
  transition: 0.1s filter;
  filter: blur(4px);
  height:99%; /* for me 99vh works too */
  display: flex;
}
```

We can adjust 99 % or vh per your other custom css or bootstrap you might be using.